# CDC cleanup doesn't work even when using sp_cdc_cleanup_change_table which completes successfully

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, change-data-capture

I'm running the query below to find CDC tables with data beyond the configured retention depth:

```sql
SELECT DB_ID() AS database_id, ct.capture_instance, object_id, source_object_id
, rcounts.source_table_rows
, rcounts.ct_table_rows
, ct_pstats.used_page_count
, source_pstats.used_page_count
, sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time(sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn(ct.capture_instance))
from cdc.change_tables AS ct
outer apply
(
select source_table_rows = (SELECT SUM(rows) FROM sys.partitions AS p WHERE p.object_id = ct.source_object_id AND p.index_id <= 1)
, ct_table_rows = (SELECT SUM(rows) FROM sys.partitions AS p WHERE p.object_id = ct.object_id AND p.index_id <= 1)
) as rcounts
outer apply
(
select used_page_count = SUM(used_page_count)
from sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ps
where ps.object_id = ct.object_id
) AS ct_pstats
outer apply
(
select used_page_count = SUM(used_page_count)
from sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ps
where ps.object_id = ct.source_object_id
) AS source_pstats
outer apply
(
select *
from msdb.dbo.cdc_jobs
where job_type = 'cleanup'
and database_id = DB_ID()
) as cleanup
WHERE DATEADD(minute, 60*25, sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time(sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn(ct.capture_instance))) < DATEADD(minute, -cleanup.retention, GETDATE())
```

This returns a lot of results where the gap between the min lsn time and the configured CDC retention is over 25 hours.

The configured retention time is 5000 minutes, and the min lsn time is over 5800 minutes at the time of this writing.

To try and resolve this, I manually executed the `cdc.cleanup` job. It was completed successfully but made no change.

I then manually executed the procedure `sp_cdc_cleanup_change_table` for each of the capture instances, and they completed successfully, but again - made no change.

```sql
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_cleanup_change_table @capture_instance = '...', @low_water_mark = NULL, @threshold = 5000;
```

We suspect that this issue is related to a fail-over that happened around the same time, but since then we have already failed over back to the original primary replica.

Can anyone advise how to resolve this latency in cleanup without having to disable and re-enable CDC?

Thanks

**Environment details:**

- SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition, version 12.0.6024
- AlwaysOn Availability Group with 3 nodes - 2 synchronous with automatic failover, and one asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here.

Okay so after a couple of days, the issue appears to have been resolved on its own.

Looks like SQL Server simply needed some more time to perform the cleanup.